# Ember View Select, only renders dropdown on full page refresh

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I am having some trouble with Ember Select.

My dropdown is on an account edit page, the box works fine on full page refresh, but as soon as you navigate to anywhere else and then back to an edit page, the dropdown simply doesn't appear, unless you fully refresh the page.

Even if you do full page refresh in the index, then click through to edit an account they do not load.

Here is a simplification of my relevant code:

```
// accounts/edit.hbs
{{ view "select" content=fieldOptions value=selection }}


// controllers/accounts/edit.hbs
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  fieldOptions = ["1", "2", "3"],
});
```

I am sure this is something really basic, but can't seem to get to the bottom of it. It just doesn't seem to render when navigating to the pagfe without a full refresh.

Comment: can you reproduce in jsbin?

Comment: `fieldOptions = ["1", "2", "3"]` should be `fieldOptions : ["1", "2", "3"]`

Comment: Works [jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/suloke/1/edit?html,css,js,output)